# webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't work as expected?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that loads a real URL something like https://example.com

I would like to open some links according to a pattern in a second webview.

I have the following code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // Handle external url
    boolean openInNew = manageUrl (url);
    Log.i("openurl", url + " : " + openInNew);
    if (openInNew) {
        this.callBack.openWebView2 (url);
        return true;
    } else {        
        return false;
    }
}
```

The second webview shows correctly the external url I want to load.

The problem I found is about what happens with the original webview, it is also redirected to an empty blank page (with a loading icon).

Is possible to keep the first webview in the original page? I thought that with shouldOverrideUrlLoading should be enough.

Maybe I forgot something, any help would be appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: return true;/return false;

Comment: Hi greenapps, what does it mean ;) ?

Comment: My provisional solution is very bad, when I load the second webview, I had to load the url for the first webview with the most recent url visited in background.

Comment: Where is your second webview? In a different activity?

Comment: I tested two scenarios. 1. Open the second webview in a new activity. 2. Open the second webview in the same activity. Even a third scenario, show a Toast message and return true without opening a new webview, so then the webview 1 always redirects a blank page with a loading icon. I had another app loading static html from assets and there shouldOverrideLoadingURL works as expected. I'm wondering if it is caused by load content from internet instance of the assets folder